# How to set a Label position after a timer ends, in a repetitive structure?

Tags: java, timer, swing

I have this fragment of code. It moves a pawn on a board.

```
while(i<end)
{
    try 
    {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
       System.out.println(e);
    }
    Label.setBounds(x+i, y, xsize, ysize);
    i++;
}
```

My problem:
The Label gets set only once, after all the time(`end` seconds) passes.

Also tried:
1:

```
while(i<end)
{
    for(int v;v<9999999;v++);
    Label.setBounds(x+i, y, xsize, ysize);
    i++;
}
```

2:

```
while(i<end)
{
    for(int v;v<9999999;v++)
    {
        Label.setBounds(x+i, y, xsize, ysize);
    }
    i++;
}
```

With same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ain't a simple task. First: i am not sure which Java Framework for windows (awt, Swing, JavaFX) you are using. Since i personally am most confident with JavaFX, i will refer to JavaFX in my answer.

Java does not repaint its interface every X miliseconds, but whenever the main thread is idle. As long as your application DOES stuff, it won't repaint, and won't show progress. So if you update your label within a loop, only the last label text will actually be repainted once the loop ends.

You could circumvent that by using a thread. A thread is like a second little program, more or less independent from the main "loop" of your application. But usually, only the main thread is allowed to change interface elements, so a second thread should not be allowed to modify the GUI from within the thread.

So how do you update the label? The answer ain't exactly simple. And it depends heavily on your framework. The basic answer is: do calculations in a separate thread, and make your GUI update from the main thread. In javaFX you could **bind** the label's text to a variable and change that variable in your second thread. Some classes, like the progressBar (fantasy name, the real class name is somewhat different) also have special calls that allow to bind it to a Task's progress property.

For further info on this for JavaFX see here: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm

A good starting point for swing is here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/

overall, this area is kinda difficult, but once you get the hang of it, you can build nice, responsive applications. It's definately worth learning.

Comment: I opted on using javax.swing.Timer in the end.

Answer (score 1):

> Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information on why this happens.

Using `javax.swing.Timer` I modified the code to this form:

```
int delay = 1000;

ActionListener taskPerformer = (ActionEvent evt) -> 
{
    Label.setBounds(x+1, y, xsize, ysize);    
    if(condition)
    {
        timer.stop();
    }
};

timer = new Timer(delay, taskPerformer);
timer.setRepeats(true);
timer.start();
```

It now works as intended.